# Linearize if statement in MILP constraint

Tags: python, optimization, binary, linearization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem in which one of the constraints is :
x*y=0, where x and y are decision variables and only x or y can be positive. In other words, if x!=0 then y=0 and if y!=0 then x=0.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assumption: `x` and `y` are nonnegative
- Infer upper-bounds `UB_x` and `UB_y` for `x`, `y`
- Introduce new boolean variable `b`
- Add constraints:

  ```
  x <= (1-b) * UB_x
  y <= b * UB_y
  ```

Comment: how to define the UB_x and the UB_y?

Comment: You must limit them a-priori building your model. Those are constants.